# Actionscript - listening to property changed event on the object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

In actionscript3, is there an event I can listen to whenever a property of an object gets updated?

I found [PropertyChangeEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/PropertyChangeEvent.html)  which is dealing with Flex event objects. I'm not familiar with Flex and what it would mean for my application to use it's components. My application is   writtien strictly in actionscript3.

**update** looks like there was something like that in actionscript-2 - [Object.watch](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001435.html)

Comment: I don't think it is possible with pure AS 3.0 but you can make something similar like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/318639/1123633

Answer (score 4):

> In actionscript3, is there an event I can listen to whenever a
>   property of an object gets updated?

No, or at least not by default!

In Flex, custom properties on objects are implemented with get/set methods and the set methods dispatch a property change event.  Something like this:

```
private var _myVar : SomeClass;
public function get myVar():SomeClass{
  return _myVar;
}

public function set myVar(value:SomeClass):void{
  _myVar = value;
  dispatchEvent(new Event('myVarChanged'));
}
```

This is primarily used for binding in the Flex Framework and most of these 'propertyChanged' events are not documented.  Every once in a while they become useful.

In non-Flex code; you're more than welcome to write your properties in the same exact manner.  I would not expect that the default Flash classes to dispatch 'propertyChanged' events.

Comment: looks like there was something like that in actionscript-2 - [Object.watch](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001435.html)

Comment: See also the Flex documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ce1.html

Answer (score 2):

According to Actionscript 3.0 Reference (http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html#bindSetter())

You can use:

```
BindingUtils.bindSetter(myFunctionHandler, entity, "property");

protected function myFunctionHandler(object:Object):void
{
    // implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use :

```
ChangeWatcher.watch(textarea, "text", watcherListener);

private function watchListener(event:Event):void
{
    // Use myWatcher.unwatch() to remove the watcher.
}
```

But if you have a class that extends "Object", if you instantiate, it would not have a dispatchEvent() method to dispatch an event . You have to extend IEventDispatcher.